# converting a string data into a dataframe in python

Tags: python, json, parsing

My String variable contains data in this format and I want to convert it to data-frame using python. Can someone guide me how to proceed.

```
    Data : data1

  Name                                             Space      
  --------------------------------      ----------------      
   A                                                 3GB        
   B                                                 0GB       
   C                                                 6MB        
   D                                                 2GB        

   T                                                 1GB        

    Data : data2

  Name                                             Space      
  --------------------------------      ----------------      
   A                                                 3GB        
   B                                                 0GB       
   C                                                 6MB        
   D                                                 2GB        

   T                                                 1GB
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps, how I would do:

1. identify and separate the tables in string data `str.split()`
2. identify the header and the data rows of the string data, keywords: foreach, tuples, lists, comprehension, map, `str.split()` etc.
3. out the data into **pandas** datafame: `DataFrame.from_records`